# State is cleared after refreshing

Tags: jstree

I am drawing different tree based on user clicked raw so I need to save many states

i am initializing tree as this

```
$('#keywordTree').jstree({
    'core': {
        'themes': {
            'icons': false
        }
    },
    "plugins": ["state"]
});
```

treeInit = true;
and after user select the row i bind data like this

```
function drewRelationTree(secondaryCode) {
    $('#keywordTree').jstree(true).settings.core.data = relationTree;
    $('#keywordTree').jstree(true).settings.state.key = secondaryCode;
    $('#keywordTree').jstree(true).refresh();
}
```

different states work when switching between different rows until i refresh the page.
Then when i cling some row the state localStorage is cleared.

So far my working solution is this:

function drewRelationTree(secondaryCode) {
$('#keywordTree').jstree(true).settings.core.data = relationTree;
$('#keywordTree').jstree(true).settings.state.key = secondaryCode;

```
var state = $.vakata.storage.get(secondaryCode);

$('#keywordTree').jstree(true).refresh(true);

setTimeout(() => {
    $.vakata.storage.set(secondaryCode, state);

    $('#keywordTree').jstree(true).restore_state();
},100);
```

}

I noticed state is reset to empty after refresh

[image]